# Why my AOSP image install fails for Samsung Note 3

Tags: android, android-source

I am trying to install an image, which I compiled myself from AOSP. I am moving the zip file to the external sd card, and using TWRP to install it. I get the following messages:

```
E: Unable to mount '/usbstorage'
Full SELinux is present
In istalling '/external_sd/full_toroplus-ota-eng.root.zip
checking for MD5 file
Skipping MD5 check: no MD5 file found.
assert failed: getprop ('ro.product.device") == "toroplus" || getprop ("ro.bild.product") ==toroplus"
e:error executing updater binary in zip 'external_sd/full_toroplus-ta-eng.root.zip'
error flashing zip '/external_sd/full_toroplus-ota-eng.root.zip
Updating partition details..
E:unable to mount 'usbstorage'
```

---

I decided to follow this link: [How To Build CyanogenMod Android for Samsung Galaxy Note 3 LTE ("hlte")](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Build_for_hlte)
But when I run breakfast, I see the following error:
    #:~/android/system# breakfast hlte
    including vendor/cm/vendorsetup.sh
    ls: cannot access device/*/hlte/cm.mk: No such file or directory
    build/core/product_config.mk:233:*  Can not locate config makefile for product "cm_hlte".  Stop.
    Device hlte not found. Attempting to retrieve device repository from CyanogenMod Github   (http://github.com/CyanogenMod).
    Found repository: android_device_samsung_hlte
    Default revision: cm-10.2
    Checking branch info
    Default revision cm-10.2 not found in android_device_samsung_hlte. Bailing.
    Branches found:
    cm-11.0
    stable/cm-11.0
    Use the ROOMSERVICE_BRANCHES environment variable to specify a list of fallback   branches.
    ls: cannot access device/*/hlte/cm.mk: No such file or directory
    build/core/product_config.mk:233: * Can not locate config makefile for product "cm_hlte".  Stop.

```
** Don't have a product spec for: 'cm_hlte'
** Do you have the right repo manifest?
```

Comment: Did you type out the errors? there appears to be spelling mistakes in the error messages them selves, it would be better if you just copy pasted the exact messages (see ro.bild.product)

Comment: There's little reason to believe that this *should* work.  If you want to end up with a build that works on the Note 3, you'd probably be better off starting with the codebase of some community ROM targeted at it (if any exist) or at least samsung-derived codebase rather than vanilla AOSP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, the best way to install an AOSP compiled image is via fastboot. However, based on this error:

```
assert failed: getprop ('ro.product.device") == "toroplus" || getprop ("ro.bild.product") ==toroplus
```

I suspect that your image wasn't compiled with the appropriate `lunch` settings for your toro device.

Comment: Just beat me to it. I agree, the title implies that the OP is creating an image for the Samsung Note 3, but toroplus is for the Google Galaxy Nexus IIRC

Comment: Yes. You are both right @ Chris Thompson & Andrew T. I appreciate your earlier comments also. I typed the message output from the phone. Someone else told me that toroplus is for Nexus also. So I decided to follow this link: http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Build_for_hlte